# How to make sense of this integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, regularization

On page 10 of [this paper on quantum field theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0405006.pdf). There is the integral:

$$\ln(N(T)) \propto \iiint\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln (\sinh(T \omega_k)) d^3k$$

where $\omega_k$ is the energy $\sqrt{|k|^2+m^2}$

Now cleary this integral is divergent. Is there any way to make sense of this integral to give function $N(T)$ that is not infinite?

For example I notice that for large $T$ and keeping the limits large but not infinite  , $\ln(N(T))\approx c T$ where $c$ is a very large number. (Perhaps dividing by a constant $c$ which depends on the limits of integration would give a finite function?)

**Edit:**

My guess would be that this is proportional to:

$$\ln(N(T)) \propto \lim_{\Lambda\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 
\iiint\limits_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda} \ln (\sinh(T \omega_k)) d^3k
}{
\iiint\limits_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda} \ln (\sinh( \omega_k)) d^3k
}$$

Which would give $\ln(N(1))=1$ so that's a finite value and hopefully this would give finite values for other values of $T$. But I can't prove it.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: isn't it divergent in UV sector as $\int k^3 dk$? And what is the observable here since if 
you're talking of renormalization to make sense of this you need an associated observable.

Comment: @aitfel in this paper, the observables are the fields on 3-space I believe.